# MFC: Set controls position at runtime

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a mfc dialog window with some button control and an activeX web browser control.
For now I am dragging-dropping the controls over my dialog window so their position is somewhat hard coded and not relative to dialog. 
I want to set their position at runtime , when the dialog window opens.

I tried doing `SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(IDC_EXPLORER), 0,0,a,b,1);` but its not doing anything.
What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetWindowPos is what you've just used the wrong parameters. The final flag you've specified SWP_NOSIZE but I don't think that's what you want. Try this:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_EXPLORER)->SetWindowPos( NULL, 0, 0, a, b, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
```

If you're looking to dynamically resize your controls based on the parent. Here's an absolute gem of a solution:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/article.php/c323/Method-to-achieve-repositioningresizing-of-child-controls.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear about if you want to change only the x-/y-position of the window or also the z-position. I assume you only want to x-/y-move it.

You need to apply SetWindowPos on the window whose position you want to change. You don't pass the window to move to SetWindowPos. And please don't pass 1 as a flag, please pass the SWP_ defines.

```
 GetDlgItem(IDC_EXPLORER)->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, 0, 0, a, b, SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOZORDER);
```

or even simpler:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_EXPLORER)->MoveWindow(0, 0, a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of controls, using [`DeferWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632681.aspx) combined with `BeginDeferWindowPos` and `EndDeferWindowPos` may improve performance and reduce flickering.

[Sample from Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/06/436043.aspx):

```
HDWP hdwp = BeginDeferWindowPos(2);
int cxHalf = cx/2;
if (hdwp) hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, g_hwndChildren[0],
             NULL, 0, 0, cxHalf, cy,
             SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
if (hdwp) hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, g_hwndChildren[1],
             NULL, cxHalf, 0, cx-cxHalf, cy,
             SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
if (hdwp) EndDeferWindowPos(hdwp);
```